# system.NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

```
Dim Permission As String
        Dim chk As String = "p"
        Permission = (ds.Tables("privilege").Rows(0).Item(0)).ToString
        MessageBox.Show(Permission)
        Dim PermissionArray() As String = Split(Permission, ":")
        For i As Integer = 0 To 36
            If PermissionArray(i) = 1 Then
                Try
                    Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls(chk & i), CheckBox)
                    chkBox.Checked = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
```

This code gives me the following error in catch, i have googled but nothing is working

This is the error: `System.NullReferenceException – Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: It should also give you a line where it happened.

Comment: @sixlettervariables it gives me error at `chkBox.Checked = True`

Comment: Then you obviously do not have a control with one of the names (see `chk & i`).

Comment: Guys i do have p0 to p36 as my checkboxes.... please consider it

Comment: Does it fail at index 0?

Comment: @Meta-Knight yes, p0 is a checkbox

Comment: Guyz i have all my checkboxes in a groupBox, so when i accessed it using `GroupBox.Controls(chk & i)` and its now working. I am so sorry to trouble you guyz.

Comment: @GoldenHeat: I was just about to give this answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted `chkBox.Checked` throws NullReferenceException, you should evaluate the following line for the error:

```
Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls(chk & i), CheckBox)

' This may throw NullReferenceException if there is no (chk & i) control available
chkBox.Checked = True
```

Comment: No i do have all the items, like "p0" to "p36"

Comment: Nope, you do not (or one of them is not a `CheckBox`).

Comment: Ok i have p0 which is a checkbox, so atleast that should work, as if error comes at any certain point things before it will remain the same, but the problem is this line does not executes `Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls(chk & i), CheckBox)` Is this line is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Although it turned out not to be your problem this time,
`Permission = (ds.Tables("privilege").Rows(0).Item(0)).ToString` 
 is a prime candidate for a  system.NullReferenceException.  This statement relies on everything in your data set being fully and correctly populated or errors can occur.

If the table "privilege" does not exist in the dataset, or the table is empty, or the first column of the first row is null, you can get exceptions and it will be very hard to tell what is wrong.  You should test those conditions before relying on the assignment, so you don't get exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you are missing one or more controls "p0" ... "p35" since blindly build the ID, ask the form for the control of that ID but never check if it was actually found. Try including the value of 'i' in your message when the exception is caught. That'll be the first control you're misisng.

And then, be sure to check the return values of functions you call before you USE those return values.

Comment: No i do have all the items, like "p0" to "p36".